# "Dynamic" mouse cursor in custom control in C# (WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms, cursor, custom-controls

I'm doing a (custom drawn) custom contol in C# (Windows.Forms).
Mouse cursor shape should depends on what part of my custom control is currently under cursor. (Let me call it "dynamic cursor": I mean that cursor depends not only on what Control is under the cursor, but also on mouse coordinates.)

When using WinAPI, I've thought that `WM_SETCURSOR` should be used as a proper way:

```
//pseusocode
if(uMsg == WM_SETCURSOR) {
    if((HWND)wParam == hwnd) {
        POINT point;
        GetCursorPos(&point);
        ScreenToClient(hwnd, &point);
        if(point.Y < ...) SetCursor(...);
        else if(point.Y < ...) SetCursor(...);
        else SetCursor(...);
        return true;
    }
    else return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

So, in C#, I hoped I I'll do smth like this:

```
protected override void OnNeedToSetCursor(NeedToSetCursorEventArgs e) {
    if(...) Cursor.Current = ...;
    else if(...) Cursor.Current = ...;
    else Cursor.Current = ...;
}
```

However, there is no such event or overridable method in `Control`.

Thus, the question is:
What is a proper way to implement such "dynamic" cursor in WinForms?

1. Should I just override `OnMouseMove`:

   ```
   protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e) {
       if(e.Y < ...) Cursor.Current = ...;
       else if(e.Y < ...) Cursor.Current = ...;
       else Cursor.Current = ...;

       base.OnMouseMove(e);
   }
   ```
2. Or should I fallback to overriding `WndProc`:

   ```
   protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
       if(m.Msg == 0x0020/*WM_SETCURSOR*/) {
           if(...) Cursor.Current = ...;
           else if(...) Cursor.Current = ...;
           else Cursor.Current = ...;

           m.Result = new IntPtr(-1);
       }
       else base.WndProc(ref m);
   }
   ```

P.S.:

Please don't answer something like: "choose yourself" or "I more like this way".
**Because this is not matter of individual preference, this is matter of correctness**.

If both ways are correct, please say "Both ways are correct". If only one way is correct, please explain why other way is incorrect. If both methods "will work", but one of them has some advantages/disadvantages (for example: "mouse-move way has greater performance overhead", or "WM_MOUSEMOVE message is not dedicated for that, thus using mouse-move way will set cursor shape too late; i.e. when mouse moves (125,19)->(125,20)->(125,21) and I set cursor shape to NS_SIZE in (125,20) it will change only in (125,21)"), please tell that.

P.P.S.: I'm disappointed in this site. What idiot could ever think that this question is opinion-based? Has he read "P.S."? Has he read the correct answer?

Comment: Yes.  You need to pick one by yourself.

Comment: @HansPassant, please see P.S.

Comment: A good reason to use mousemove, is that the positioning of x and y to the relative position of the control is already done for you. When using a message, you have to do a PointToClient(Cursor.Position) first. Not exactly earth shocking, but mouse move was made for our convenience.

Comment: @Me.Name, yes, I understand that. But then what message WM_SETCURSOR is for? If WM_MOUSEMOVE (OnMouseMove) is enough, why did Microsoft created WM_SETCURSOR event? Doesn't setting cursor in WM_MOUSEMOVE (OnMouseMove) have some drawbacks/side effects?

Comment: All right then, then I'd also like to add, that as far as I know (no proof though), the work for mousemove is done, regardless whether the method gets overridden. If that indeed is the case, strictly performance wise, redoing the check and cursor conversions in wndproc would ultimately give greater performance overhead.

Comment: Hey, your comment didn't contain the  WM_SETCURSOR versus WM_MOUSEMOVE before. Must have missed your edit. The difference between the 2 is that mousemove isn't sent to an underlying window if it is captured. You can test that by adding a webbrowser control to your form. SetCursor will still be fired if over the webbrowser control, but MouseMove will not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is:

Only `WM_SETCURSOR` (but not `OnMouseMove)` can be used in this case.

Using `Cursor.Current = ...` in `OnMouseMove` will cause persistent cursor flickering.